# Interfacing with synchronous code from boost::asio

Tags: c++, asynchronous, boost, boost-asio

I have a program, written using boost::asio, which at its core is a TCP client (my program, not boost::asio, obviously :). However, from that code I need to call into a library, that might perform blocking network i/o, which will stall the execution of a single-threaded boost::asio part.

What is the common approach for making calls into synchronous code from asynchronous code without stalling the event loop?

The library in question can not be modified (third-party code), so there's no way to alter its behaviour w.r.t. blocking i/o.

Comment: If you cannot get the handler of the socket of the synchronous call, then you need to move the synchronous call into another thread. Like: std::async

Comment: @WeiGuo Let's assume I use std::async to perform the blocking operation. When the operation completes, how do I call the callback in the "main thread"?

Comment: You can wrap you blocking operation and the callback function in a lambda function. And call the lambda in std::async.